how can I configure nginx config with php ratchet webscoket?
I need to configure the websocket service written in PHP ratchet in yii2 application with nginx service. I find the same configs for websocket connection in the internet, but I faced unexpected error when I try to connect my service my service is handling handshake request and validates request but the connection status is frozen in pending
my websocket service is running on the server on port 8086, I wanted to redirect all requests and connections to this service when it comes to the socket url through nginx. but something is working wrong here is my configuration:
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
 "text/html" epoch;
 "text/html; charset=utf-8" epoch;
 default off;
}
server {
 charset utf-8;
 server_name domain.uz www.domain.uz;
 listen 80;
 gzip on;
 gzip_types text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
 gzip_min_length 1000;

 location /sock/ {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8086;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade "Websocket";
 proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
 }

 if ($host = www.domen.uz) {
 return 301 https://domen.uz$request_uri;
 }
}

If I open my port 8086 to the firewall and send a handshake request to my service in the form of ip-address:8086, it receives it and the connection is opened.
but if I make a request for this with the URL ws://domen.uz/sock, a handshake request is sent to my service, it passes all the steps, but remains in the connecting status
and when I set this header as follows:
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
The upgrade header is not reaching my service, that is, nginx is not sending it to the middle, as far as I know, if you write the name of the header after $http_, it should have given the value of this header
my stack is:
nginx version:
~$ sudo nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

ubuntu version:
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

websocket service: php ratchet websocket
I try to find any problem related to this but I cannot find it. I think this is related to something little setting
sorry for my english I'm not native it and I try to my best )
